# Request.getParameter with JSP

Tags: jsp

I'm trying to auto-populate a drop down list based on a request parameter. I'm fairly new to JSP so forgive me for the simple question.

The following works fine and displays the alert correctly:

```
 alert('<%=request.getParameter("lang") %>');
```

So I know what I am trying to do is easy enough. But when I add this same logic in with my select statement using:

```
<option <c:if test="${request.getParameter(\"lang\")=='En'}"> selected="selected" </c:if>    value="<c:out value="${english}"/>">English</option>
```

I get an exception saying "The function getParameter must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified".

I'm a little confused as to why this doesn't work here...

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you declared your taglib (`<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" 
    prefix="c" %>`)?

Comment: Yes, I had actually. Good answer below

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`request.getParameter()` will not resolved by EL. Request parameter can be accessed using implicit variable `param`. i.e, `${param.lang}`

Change this

```
<option <c:if test="${request.getParameter(\"lang\")=='En'}"> selected="selected" </c:if>    value="<c:out value="${english}"/>">English</option>
```

to

```
<option <c:if test="${param.lang == 'En'}"> selected="selected" </c:if> value="${english}">English</option>
```

Comment: Thanks. Very new to JSP so didn't know that.

Comment: what is the use of <c:out value="${english}"? what is english here? literal or EL variable?

Comment: yeah ! why `<c:out value="${english}"/>` instead of `${english}` ?

Comment: if it is elexpression , `${english}` is enough instead of  `<c:out value="${english}"/>`

Answer (score 3):

another way :

```
<option <c:if test='${param[lang] == "En"}'> selected="selected" </c:if>
    value="${english}">

    English
</option>
```

Make sure you have added c-taglibs URI on top of the JSP.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```