# never be able to get actual value through request.getParameter() in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have code :

```
<%
ResultSet topicResult = DatabaseManager.getTopics(sujectResult.getString("_id"));
out.print("<ul class=\"pages\">");
while (topicResult.next()) {
%>
<li<% String selectedTopic = request.getParameter("topic_id");
try{
    if(selectedTopic.equals(topicResult.getString("_id"))){%>
class="selected"
<%}
}catch(NullPointerException e){

}%>
><a href="/programming-iqs/admin-controller?action=manage-content&topic_id=
<%= topicResult.getString("_id")%>">
<%= topicResult.getString("topic_name")%>
</a></li>
<%
}

}
%>
```

in the code given above I could get value of

```
request.getParameter("topic_id");
```

but when I try the code which is in same page and is about 20 lines below of above one :

```
<%

String topicAttr = request.getParameter("topic_id"); // Here velue is NULL

try{
    if (!topicAttr.equals(null)){
    ResultSet subjByIdResult = DatabaseManager.getTopicById(topicAttr);
        while(subjByIdResult.next()){
            out.print(subjByIdResult.getString("topic_name"));
        }
    }
}catch(NullPointerException e){

}
%>
```

I never be able to get actual value but the `null`.
I searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873020/request-getparameter-with-jsp) & [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936738/unable-to-retrieve-the-passed-value-from-jsp-to-controller-using-url-via-a-butto), but un-able to find solution in my case.
Can any one please suggest me a solution of this.

Comment: Code review: `topicAttr.equals(null)` will always be false or a NullPointerException. Use `topicAttr == null`.

Comment: where do you set the value of  `topic_id` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should store first occurrence of your `request.getParameter()` in String variable. Then you can use it globally.

Also change your `if` condition to

```
if (!topicAttr.equals==null){}
```

Because in equals() method you compare `String` with variables.

Comment: Are you sure that the variable wont be available for the second occurrence ?

Comment: I am sure. But I have not mentioned anything like it in my answer. I just told to store in any variable to use in rest of code. Why receive it multiple times.

Comment: Code review: use `something != somethingElse` instead of `! something == somethingElse`